# A (hard?) problem on congruences

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I have a lot of trouble finding if this is true or not.

Suppose that $a_1,\ldots, a_d$ are natural numbers in $[0,n)$ such that $\sum a_i = 0$ mod $n$ and $(a_i,n) = 1$ for all $i$. I would like to show that if there exists $m<n$ such that $\sum \overline{ma_i} = n$, where $\overline{ma_i}\in [0,n)$ is the representative of $ma_i$ in $\mathbb Z_n$, then there exists $m'$ such that $\sum\overline{m'a_i} = n$ and $(m',n) =1$.

Every example I have considered satisfies this property. The trouble I have is that I cannot really apply theory on $\mathbb Z_n$, since sometimes I have to consider them as number.

If $d>n$, then it is easy to see that no d-tuples satisfy the hypothesis. So we can restrict to the case where $d\leq n$. Moreover, if $d> n/2$, then any tuples satifying the hypothesis will contain 1's, so $m$ will already be coprime to $n$. So we can restrict ourselves to $d\leq n/2$. I am not sure if it helps.

Thanks!